# Tool Header in XML-View

Tags: sapui5

I've started with my first SAPUI5 application and I wanna use the Tool Header item like in the [Demo Kit](https://ui5.sap.com/#/sample/sap.tnt.sample.ToolHeader/preview).
(I'm using an XML-View.)

I've included it into my view but now I get the error:

> UIComponent.js:6 Uncaught Error: failed to load 'sap/tnt/ToolHeader.js' from resources/sap/tnt/ToolHeader.js: 404 - Not Found

Do I have embed a special script in my application? (Which one?)

page.view.xml

```
<mvc:View
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m" 
    xmlns:tnt="sap.tnt" 
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    controllerName="zdemo.controller.MachDetail">

    <tnt:ToolHeader>
        <Button icon="sap-icon://menu2" type="Transparent">
            <layoutData>
                <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow" />
            </layoutData>
        </Button>
        <ToolbarSpacer width="20px" />
        <Button text="File" type="Transparent">
            <layoutData>
                <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low" />
            </layoutData>
        </Button>
        <Button text="Edit" type="Transparent">
            <layoutData>
                <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low" />
            </layoutData>
        </Button>
        <Button text="View" type="Transparent">
            <layoutData>
                <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low" />
            </layoutData>
        </Button>
        <Button text="Navigate" type="Transparent">
            <layoutData>
                <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low" />
            </layoutData>
        </Button>
        <Button text="Code" type="Transparent">
            <layoutData>
                <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low" />
            </layoutData>
        </Button>
        <Button text="Refactor" type="Transparent">
            <layoutData>
                <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low" />
            </layoutData>
        </Button>
        <Button text="Run" type="Transparent">
            <layoutData>
                <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low" />
            </layoutData>
        </Button>
        <Button text="Tools" type="Transparent">
            <layoutData>
                <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low" />
            </layoutData>
        </Button>
        <tnt:ToolHeaderUtilitySeparator />
        <ToolbarSpacer>
            <layoutData>
                <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow" minWidth="20px" />
            </layoutData>
        </ToolbarSpacer>
        <Button text="Alan Smith" type="Transparent" press="handleUserNamePress">
            <layoutData>
                <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow" />
            </layoutData>
        </Button>

    </tnt:ToolHeader>
</mvc:View>
```

the only one script in my index.html

```
<script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex" id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{ "zdemo":"./"
    }'>
```

Comment: The ToolHeader has been added with 1.34. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, but according to the comments, you are using an older version which does not yet include the ToolHeader control.

By upgrading to SAPUI5 1.34+ you will be able to use the ToolHeader with the same code.

The [documentation for the control](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.tnt.ToolHeader) includes the information when the control was added.

Answer (score 0):

You need import module dependency "sap.tnt" to your project. You can do it this way:

**1. install dependency via bower**

```
bower install openui5/packaged-sap.tnt
```

if you need another dependency, you can find here: https://github.com/openui5

**2. add reference lib to index.html**

```
<script .... data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.tnt"></script>
```

**3. if you use grunt serve, expose dependency resources by openui5_connect**

on file Gruntfile.js, find openui5_connect key and add

```
openui5_connect: {
    options: {
        resources: [
            ...
            'bower_components/openui5-sap.tnt/resources',
        ],
        testresources: [
            ...
            'bower_components/openui5-sap.tnt/test-resources'
        ]
    }
}
```

**4. To finish, add dependency entry to manifest.json**

```
"sap.ui5": {
    "dependencies": {
        "libs": {
            ...
            "sap.tnt": {}
        }
    }
}
```

And run your app